# backwards compatibility in deluge

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, deluge

ubuntu 20.04 lts comes out with deluge 2.x but my setup includes a windows machine for wich there is no 2.x client yet. Will i be able to remain on the 1.3.x branch when updating ubuntu server to 20.04 lts?
So far the only solution i came up with has been not to upgrade those particular machines.

Relevant machines are:

- server (pc, ubuntu server 18.04 lts)
- client0 (pc, ubuntu gnome 18.04 lts)
- client1 (pc, windows 10)
- client2 (mobile, android 10)
- client3 (laptop, ubuntu gnome 18.04 lts)
- client4 (tablet, android 8)

or is there a way where the android devices (for which there are also only 1.3.x clients) and the windows device don't block my upgrade path?

edit: just for clarification: i'm talking about the deluged server to which deluge clients connect to actually control what's happening on the server machine.

Comment: "or is there a way where the android devices (for which there are also only 1.3.x clients) and the windows device don't block my upgrade path?" we don't know ask an android or windows user ;-)  "includes a windows machine for wich there is no 2.x client yet." and why do you believe this is an issue? A torrent is a torrent. Regardless of the version of the software. Why would a v2.0 on Linux interfere with a deluge on another OS?!

Comment: problem is: no deluge 1.3.x client can log onto a deluged 2.x server [1]
"Upgrade considerations

Deluge 2.0 is not compatible with Deluge 1.x clients or daemons so these will require upgrading too. Also third-party Python scripts may not be compatible if they directly connect to the Deluge client and will need migrating."
[1] https://deluge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/2.0.html